# Mysql comparing records within same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a tables which essentially logs key activities to certain records. These Key activities are Create, Archive, and Unarchive, and basically might look a bit like this basically between the 'Create' and 'Archive', and 'Unarchive' and 'Archive' the object is 'Active'.

```
id | object_id |  Object  |   action    | log_date
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |     1     |  Obj     |  Create     | 2016-02-05
2  |     2     |  Obj     |  Create     | 2016-02-07
3  |     3     |  Obj     |  Create     | 2016-02-08
4  |     1     |  Obj     |  Archived   | 2016-02-27
5  |     2     |  Obj     |  Archived   | 2016-02-15
6  |     2     |  Obj     |  UnArchive  | 2016-02-25
7  |     3     |  Obj     |  Archived   | 2016-03-10
```

What i am needing to do is to is be able to say on the 1st March 2016, there was 2 objects active, and they have been active for an average of 21.3 days (object 3 was active for 20 days, and object 2 was reactivated for 3 days as the time of 2016-03-01 leading average of 21.3).

EDIT: 
So the dataset which would be used is as followed:

```
id | object_id |  Object  |    action  | log_date
---------------------------------------------------
3  |     3     |  Obj     | Create     | 2016-02-08
6  |     2     |  Obj     | UnArchived | 2016-02-25
```

Log id 3, object 3 because it was created before 1st March. and hadn't been archived at that point, and log id 6 object id 2 because it had been unarchived before march. Im not so much interested in the total time of active per each object, just time active based on its last 'create' or 'unarchive' event.

I then need to be able to do this for the 1 of each month between any given range of dates.

My first attack is to try and isolate the records which fit the requirements

```
select object_id from log l 
where object = 'Obj'
AND object_id in (SELECT object_id from log where object = 'Obj' and `action`='Create' and log_date <= '2016-10-01')
and object_id not in (select object_id from log where object = 'Obj' and `action`='Archive' group by object_id having max(log_date) < '2016-10-01')
group by object_id
```

how ever I'm not too sure where i can go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the 1st of the month criterion affect the averages?

Comment: Problem: transitions between 'active' and 'not active' states for the same object are split over multiple rows, making your query difficult to write. Suggestion: using the hand-drawn data you've posted, hand-draw a second where all the data you need to write a simple query are on the same row. Post this and someone will suggest how to transform from one data set to the other.

Comment: @Strawberry The first of the month is an arbitrary selection based on that the rest of our reports are on a monthly basis. but in this instance its like going back in time to the first and not counting beyond that point

Comment: @onedaywhen Thank you for your suggestion, i have updated the post to include the sample data set i would want to work with in this scenario. do you beleive a larger data sample would be beneficial?

Comment: I disagree with onedaywhen's analysis -although I think a more thoroughly representative data set and desired result set may prove beneficial viz. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The kind of simply query I mean would be something like `WHERE 'first_day_of_the_month' BETWEEN 'start_date' and 'end_date'` so you need two dates on the same row, the earlier date for 'date became active' and the later for 'date became inactive' (e.g. a far future date if still currently active).